# Object moving in a hollow pipe, want collision detection, how do I do that?

Tags: unity, c#

Do I need to add a rigidbody and sort the collider to fit to both the pipe and the object? I'd like the game to end if the object touches the pipe.

I've only seen sphere and box colliders. How would it work with a hollow pipe?

Comment: Is the pipe a model? You could try using the [Mesh Collider](http://docs.unity3d.com/Manual/class-MeshCollider.html)

Comment: collision detection might work  same as it work with sphere  and box

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Let me start by stating the assumption that you have imported a mesh to use as your hollow pipe. If this is not what you are currently doing, it will either not work, or be far more complicated than it needs to be. This answer might be a bit more in-depth than you were looking for, but I feel it is more important to explain the *concepts* behind what your wanting to do, in order to greatly expand what you can actually do with your game.

#### Setting up the `Collider` on your hollow pipe

The first thing we need to do is add a collider to your pipe. We can not use the generic `CapsuleCollider`, as although it fits the rough shape, it does not give us the hollow center we need to move the player.

You want to add a `MeshCollider` component via the inspector. With your hollow pipe selected, scroll to the bottom of the inspector, and select "Add Component". From here, you can look at all the possible components you can add to your game object. This is very useful for seeing what is available, as alternates or in general. For example, if you type "collider" in to the search bar, it will show you all the available `Collider` components. We want to select "Mesh Collider".

[image: Searching for "collider" via "Add Componenets" on the Inspector]

Assuming you have a `Mesh` attached to your game object (the model of your hollow pipe - set this up, first!), the `MeshCollider` should automatically store a reference to it under its *Mesh* parameter. While the default is to use the same mesh used to render the game object, you can change the `MeshCollider` to any other mesh you may have. We won't need to do this, now, but it is useful to know. For example, if you were to create a complex character model, you could save a copy containing far less polygons to use as the collider. This would make collision easier to manage, as Unity would be dealing with a less-complex shape.

You will also want to ensure that both *Convex* and *Is Trigger* are left unchecked, although you should not be able to check *Is Trigger* unless *Convex* is already checked. This tells Unity that this collider will enforce collision detection, and force other colliders (the player, for example) to bounce off it. You don't necessarily want this behavior, but it prevents the player from clipping through the pipe in ideal circumstances, so it goes towards quality improvements.

#### Setting up the player

The player will also need a `Collider`, but we can leave it up to you to decide what type fits best. Again, ensure that no matter what, *Is Trigger* is not selected. You will also want a `RigidBody`. It is important to note that a `RigidBody` is required on at least *one* of the game objects involved in a potential collision. Without it, Unity will not detect a collision. Since `RigidBody` also manages the physics side of things, you will probably already need to have one on the player. Apart from that, it is usually best to place it on the *moving* object, if you are not entirely sure what side to implement it on.

*If you find yourself having to place a `RigidBody` on a stationary object*, you can use the *Constraints* fields at the bottom of the component view to lock movement and/or rotation along the X, Y and Z axis. You would probably also want to ensure *Use Gravity* is deselected. Again, none of this should apply to this example, but it is good to know.

#### Handling the collision

As far as basic collision goes, that should pretty much set you up. Assuming you are not going at crazy speeds, your character should "bounce off" the hollow pipe. But how do you set the game up to react to the collision with "Game Over"? Why, with some basic scripting!

Add a script to your player. Any script will do, as long as it still inherits from `MonoBehaviour`. Any script that inherits from `MonoBehaviour` will have a bunch of different functions called under certain situations, and a bunch of them are for collision. [You can check them all out at the Unity API](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/MonoBehaviour.html); it is ***extremely*** helpful, and will definitely broaden your horizons on exactly *what* you can react to in your code.

There are two types of collision you will generally handle events for, in 3D; `OnCollision` and `OnTrigger`. Remember how we made sure our colliders were not set to *Is Trigger*? Trigger collisions, where we want to know if an object is within a certain area but do not want to force physical collision, is handled differently to physical collisions. They also take in different information;

- `OnCollision` takes in an actual `Collision` object, which represents the collision, itself. From this you can derive the other game object involved, as well as other information, such as the point of contact and the applied velocity.
- `OnTrigger` takes in just the `Collider` of the object we hit, itself. In context of using `OnTrigger`, we do not need to know about the other stuff. We only really want to know *what* we collided with.

There are also *three* different events for each of these collision types. It might sound confusing, now, but with practice you will see how it all comes together. If you are familiar with input, and the likes of `GetKey`, `GetKeyUp` and `GetKeyDown`, it is the same principle.

- `OnCollisionEnter` | `OnTriggerEnter`: calls on the **first** frame where the collision occurs. You would put code here that you wish to carry out *the instant* there is a collision, but would not wish to repeat itself *for each frame* where there is collision. A player initially receiving a buff for touching a magic fountain, for example.
- `OnCollisionStay` | `OnTriggerStay`: calls on every frame where there is collision **after** the first frame. You would put code here that you wish to repeat for as long as there is collision. A player slowly taking damage while they are touching a spiky obstacle, for example.
- `OnCollisionExit` | `OnTriggerExit`: calls on the frame where the collision has first **ended**. You would put code here that you wish to carry out on the first instance where there is *no longer* collision.

You are looking for the `OnCollisionEnter(Collision collisionInfo)` method. Simply set up a simple script, as follows, and work your way from there.

```
using UnityEngine;   // we are using the UnityEngine library

public class Player : MonoBehaviour   // Our player script inherits from MonoBehaviour
{
    void OnCollisionEnter(Collision collisionInfo)
    {
        Debug.Log("Colliding with " + collisionInfo.gameObject.ToString(); 
    }
}
```

#### When things get more complex, manage your collision with tags

One final word of advice: *as you describe*, you initially have a very simply game. A player and a hollow pipe. Eventually, maybe even already, you will have a lot more objects. Some of them will also have colliders, and you may not want to have the player automatically die when they trigger `OnCollisionEnter` with *every* non-trigger collider at play. This is where *tags* come in. [You can read up on them via the Unity Manual](https://docs.unity3d.com/Manual/Tags.html), but basically, you can give objects unique tags and look for the tags in the collision code with `collisionInfo.gameObject.tag` or `collider.tag` to determine *exactly* what it is you have collided with.

Comment: Will be trying this out within the next hours. I've constructed the cylinder and I'm just doing the finishing touch on the plane to move within in.

Answer (score -1):

Put a `RigidBody` and respective `Collider` on the object you want to move around. Then, put a `MeshCollider` on the pipe. These can be selected from the component button. Then, add physics whenever you click on an object.

Afterwards, hit play and watch it go through the pipe! Note that the pipe doesn't need a `RigidBody` to have it collide with the moving object.

Comment: Have you fixed it yet?

Comment: I meant it was under the physics components in the editor, man. I was simply trying to help @Paze out. Sorry. Once you've added the correct physics to the object, try adding this code to the Pipe (not at my computer, so I'm winging it!):         //in JS//       OnCollisionEnter(coll : Collider) {              if (coll.transform.name == "player") { Destroy(coll.gameObject); Application.LoadLevel("//menu//"): }

Comment: I was going to reinterpret it in C# (as the asker lists using c#), but the code itself could be problematic. `transform.name` gives the *object name*, and will not work if the user has not named their player object "player". Same issue as tags, obviously, but why not just use tags? The asker might also get confused when they hit errors from not having a "menu" scene in their build index. That is, if they could run `Application.LoadLevel` to begin with. It is marked as *obsolete* and can throw errors that prevent the code from compiling.

Comment: If you intend to amend your answer, later, be sure to use the currently used [Scene Manager](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/SceneManagement.SceneManager.html) for moving between scenes.